# .net connection to JDEdwards 9.1

Tags: c#, sql, .net, soap, jdedwards

I am working on .net application which needs to connect to JD Edwards 9.1 (not in AS400) database to query tables and also call business function. 
Could someone tell me:

1. What .net driver i need to install and from where?
2. What would the connection string be like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JD Edwards EnterpriseOne is compatible with both MS SQL and Oracle SQL server (in addition to AS400, which you have indicated you are not using).  You need to check with your CNC (Configurable Network Computing) Administrator to determine what database type (and therefore what client software to use), as well as what the connection information is.

In some organizations, direct SQL access to JD Edwards is frowned upon and you may instead end up having to use BSSV, AIS, or a custom CSV report or Table Conversion to provide the data.

If you want to call business functions you should look into the BSSV (Business Services Server) but this generally involves writing code in Java to expose the business functions that you want to invoke.